# OpenCV gives previous frames

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

I am using OpenCVLibrary330 and I get frames through onCameraFrame function , I store it into an ArrayList by cloning (inputFrame.clone())current frame and convert it into jpg when ArrayList has at least 10 files.
But many times I get previous frames not the current frame.

```
    public static ArrayList<Mat> frames = new ArrayList<>();
    private static int indexNo = 0;
    @Override
        public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
                mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
                frames.add(indexNo,mRgba.clone());
                indexNo++;

            return inputFrame.rgba();

        }
```